# How am I able to access a remote server, when OUTPUT chain is set to DROP?

Tags: debian, iptables

I have set the default OUTPUT policy to DROP.

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

I have allowed exceptions for port 22 only.

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:22
```

```
psql -U username master_db  -p 5139 -h remotehost.net
```

How is it possible to connect to a remote database via psql when everything should be blocked? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh in case someone else comes across this issue. Remember to also block your IPv6.

```
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Otherwise postgres will use IPv6 by default and traffic still goes through.